# Cryptic Crossword #3: Words on Wheels

Tags: crosswords, cryptic-crosswords

Calling all puzzlers! Bailey M is back with Cryptic Crossword #3. Good luck, and enjoy!

[image: Crossword]

### Across

1. Finished sculpture is a total letdown (8,4)
8. Exist as god of secret material (3)
9. Rhetorical Spanish street has eleven variations (7)
10. Measure boundless squats/tumbles at open-source hub (5)
13. Very first to engrave on kind of flowering plant (5)
14. Break commoner's first-half astounding lead (5)
15. Baby chicken's two eyes (7)
17. Single cell busts a ring beam (6)
19. Highest point of a weird, airy shrubbery (7)
20. Flag penne pasta, in one end and out the other, first; timeless agent, second (7)
22. Atrocious gruel is knocked down a peg, gets eighth new start (6)
27a. Confuse right tonsil with another bodily cavity (7)
27b. No initial shortage of endlessly tall half-giants in regret (9)
29. A site to the west-southwest? Turn around, you're mixing it up with a vulnerable species (5)
30. In a surprise twist, three hundred Greeks take in Eastern European catholic (5)
31. From right to left, feed like cattle on sugary coating (5)
32. Cheese has its own chocolatey dessert (7)
33. Residual powder has become obscured (3)
34. Toothy birds, left unchained, become cutthroat (12)

### Down

1. California company's cotton cloth (6)
2. Top ten mixed martial artists start mauling you and I horribly (7)
3. Running late, single cats make milk (7)
4. At center, all eyes on friend flipping a fish (7)
5. Legacy spoke of insect's adventure (7)
6. Hold roast over cooking range (5)
7. Cathy capsizes a boat (5)
8. Flyer's flutters (4)
11. Emphasize that you stuffed yourself full of stomach pastes (9)
12. Dog misbehaves once in a rolling tire (7)
16. Dry-injected polysaccharides (4)
17. Truly, name is awful (4)
18. Self-ambition makes an unfortunate point (3,4)
21. Destroy with blend of root and condensed performance-enhancing drugs (7)
22. Fish in simple shelter has an incomplete alibi (7)
23. Voila! I reveal original mashed pasta (7)
24. Turns evildoing from head to toe (7)
25. Say hear-say, mostly? Blasphemy! (6)
26. Painting of country with masthead (5)
27. It's nearly night! (4)
28. If you're this tall, you have to stop (5)

---

**NOTE:** Partial answers are gladly accepted and teamwork is highly encouraged!

Comment: I suppose in the course of solving the significance of the blue and yellow squares will become apparent?

Comment: @dennisdeems it definite should, yes.

Comment: You're back? I thought it was me who was back? ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor you're back...and so are cryptic crosswords! Hooray for puzzling!

Comment: +1 btw; I like the look of the clues, although I haven't quite managed to crack any of them yet.

Comment: @dennisdeems I imagine that 27bA and 11D are spiral answers that go around the blue and yellow squares respectively.

Comment: These clues are fantastic.

Comment: @dennisdeems I'm glad to hear it :D I put a lot of thought into making tricky cryptics so I'm glad they're appreciated.

Comment: Just reiterating the other comments - very satisfying surface reading and nice level of difficulty - clearly you've put a lot of thought in - great job!

Comment: I'm also back, and glad to upvote a fellow cryptic-crossword-setter. :)

Comment: @BaileyM, what site/tool do you use to generate your crosswords?

Comment: @NeedAName good ol' fashioned Microsoft Excel. :)

Comment: Can someone explain how to interpret the wheels? I see no way to rotate the letters to make new words.

Comment: @Kingrames the wheels are just nine-letter words, each one circling around the wheel. They don't actually rotate at all.

Comment: @Kingrames they are, aren't they?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The completed crossword

> [image]

### An explanation of the clues

**Across:**

1A. Finished sculpture is a total letdown (8,4)

> COMPLETE BUST  (Refers to both a finished sculpture, and a total letdown)  -- credit to GentlePurpleRain

8A. 8. Exist as god of secret material (3)

> BRA ? B+RA. "Exist" is B; RA is the Egyptian god of the sun

9A. Rhetorical Spanish street has eleven variations (7)

> LEXICAL: anagram of CALLE+XI

10A. Measure boundless squats/tumbles at open-source hub (5)

> QUOTA: boundless squats = QUAT, open-source = O, O is the hub, so QUOAT, tumbles at the hub QUOTA - credit to LeppyR64

13A. Very first to engrave on kind of flowering plant (5)

> VETCH: V+ETCH (first letter of "very" plus etch = engrave)

14A. Break commoner's first-half astounding lead (5)

> COMMA: first half of commoner is COMM, first letter of astounding is A

15A. Baby chicken's two eyes (7)

> PEEPERS(!): double definition

17A. Single cell busts a ring beam (6)

> AMOEBA anagram of A+O("ring")+BEAM

19A. Highest point of a weird, airy shrubbery (7)

> TOPIARY: TOP(highest point) + anagram of AIRY

20A. Flag penne pasta, in one end and out the other, first; timeless agent, second (7)

> PENNANT: first, take either end of PENNe pastA; second, "agent" minus age (time) = NT

22A. Atrocious gruel is knocked down a peg, gets eighth new start (6)

> HORRID   (Atrocious = **horrid**;  gruel = **porridge**, knocked down a peg (remove the word **peg**) = **orrid**; gets eighth new start = use the eighth letter of the alphabet (**H**) to give it a "new start" (put it on the beginning))  -- credit to GentlePurpleRain

27a. Confuse right tonsil with another bodily cavity (7)

> NOSTRIL: anagram of R TONSIL  :D !!

27b. No initial shortage of endlessly tall half-giants in regret (9)

> NOSTALGIA:  NO + S (initial letter of shortage) + TAL (tall without final letter) + GIA (half of "giants").  As @GentlePurpleRain anticipated, this entry spirals around the blue square.

29A. A site to the west-southwest? Turn around, you're mixing it up with a vulnerable species (5)

> VENUE: anagram of ENE+VU (West-southwest turned around is east-northeast, or **ENE**. (Thanks @GentlePurpleRain.)  Vulnerable species is [conservation status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_status) VU.

30A. In a surprise twist, three hundred Greeks take in Eastern European catholic (5)

> UNIAT: anagram ("surprise twist") of TAU+IN.  tau has a value of 300 in Greek numerals and Uniate relates to certain eastern European Christian communities -- credit to Pete

31A. From right to left, feed like cattle on sugary coating (5)

> GLAZE   (Sugary coating = **glaze**.  Feed like cattle = **graze**, and change the **r**ight to a **l**eft (**R** to **L**) to give **glaze**)  -- credit to GentlePurpleRain

32A. Cheese has its own chocolatey dessert (7)

> BROWNIE: BRIE containing OWN

33A. Residual powder has become obscured (3)

> ASH: anagram of "has"

34A. Toothy birds, left unchained, become cutthroat (12)

> BLOODTHIRSTY(!): anagram of TOOTHY BIRDS L

**Down:**

1D. California company's cotton cloth (6)

> CALICO   (**Cali**fornia **Co**mpany, and **calico** is a type of cotton cloth)  -- credit to GentlePurpleRain

2D. Top ten mixed martial artists start mauling you and I horribly (7)

> MAXIMUM: anagram of X+MMA+M+UI  (ten = X, mixed martial arts = MMA, start of "mauling" = M, you and I = UI)

3D. Running late, single cats make milk (7)

> LACTATE  (Not entirely sure, but single cats = **cat**, mix with **late** to get anagram of **lactate** (make milk). -- credit to GentlePurpleRain

4D. At center, all eyes on friend flipping a fish (7)

> TILAPIA: All eyes on friend = I + PAL + I, At center = A + IPALI + T, Flipping = TILAPIA  – credit to LeppyR64

5D. Legacy spoke of insect's adventure (7)

> BEQUEST: homophone (Bee Quest!)

6D. Hold roast over cooking range (5)

> STOVE: hidden in roaST OVEr

7D. Cathy capsizes a boat (5)

> YACHT  (**Cathy** anagrams to **yacht**, which is a boat)  -- credit to GentlePurpleRain

8D. Flyer's flutters (4)

> BATS: double def.

11D. Emphasize that you stuffed yourself full of stomach pastes (9)

> OVERSTATE: "you stuffed yourself" is OVERATE; it's full of ST which is the "stomach" (interior) of "pastes". –- credit to LeppyR64

12D. Dog misbehaves once in a rolling tire (7)

> TERRIER: TIER(anagram of "tire") containing ERR

16D. Dry-injected polysaccharides (4)

> ARID: contained in polysacch**arid**es

17D. Truly, name is awful (4)

> AMEN: anagram of "name"

18D. Self-ambition makes an unfortunate point (3,4)

> OWN GOAL: double definition (going out on a limb here as I know nothing about sports, but I believe a score on one's own goal is unfortunate)

21D. Destroy with blend of root and condensed performance-enhancing drugs (7)

> TORPEDO ("condensed performance-enhancing drugs" gives PED; torpedo is an anagram of "root ped" and things can be destroyed with it) -- credit to rand al'thor

22D. Fish in simple shelter has an incomplete alibi (7)

> HALIBUT : HUT containing ALIB ("alibi" missing final letter)

23D. Voila! I reveal original mashed pasta (7)

> RAVIOLI: anagram of VOILA+I+R (first letter of "reveal")

24D. Turns evildoing from head to toe (7)

> INNINGS: take the first letter of SINNING and move it to the end

25D. Say hear-say, mostly? Blasphemy! (6)

> HERESY: here+sy (homophone of "hear" = HERE, most of "say" = SY)

26D. Painting of country with masthead (5)

> MURAL: M+URAL (first letter of "mast" replacing the first letter of rural)

27D. It's nearly night! (4)

> NIGH: most of "night"

28D. If you're this tall, you have to stop (5)

> STALL: concealed in "thiS TALL"

Comment: You might want to add that the two "wheel" words are Nostalgia and Overstate.

Answer (score 3):

### Partial answer

Here are a few I managed to get:

**Across**

1A. Finished sculpture is a total letdown (8,4)

> COMPLETE BUST  (Refers to both a finished sculpture, and a total letdown)

22A. Atrocious gruel is knocked down a peg, gets eighth new start (6)

> HORRID   (Atrocious = **horrid**;  gruel = **porridge**, knocked down a peg (remove the word **peg**) = **orrid**; gets eighth new start = use the eighth letter of the alphabet (**H**) to give it a "new start" (put it on the beginning))

29A. A site to the west-southwest? Turn around, you're mixing it up with a vulnerable species (5)

> <strike>SCENE  (A site = **scene**; west-southwest turned around is east-northeast, or **ENE**.  Mix that up with a vulnerable species (one with **c**onservation **s**tatus) to get **scene**.</strike>

31A. From right to left, feed like cattle on sugary coating (5)

> GLAZE   (Sugary coating = **glaze**.  Feed like cattle = **graze**, and change the **r**ight to a **l**eft (**R** to **L**) to give **glaze**)

**Down**

1D. California company's cotton cloth (6)

> CALICO   (**Cali**fornia **Co**mpany, and **calico** is a type of cotton cloth)

3D. Running late, single cats make milk (7)

> LACTATE  (Not entirely sure, but single cats = **cat**, mix with **late** to get anagram of **lactate** (make milk).

7D. Cathy capsizes a boat (5)

> YACHT  (**Cathy** anagrams to **yacht**, which is a boat)

Comment: Argh! I was so close with 7D, just didn't find the right anagram :-(

Comment: I am astounded by 22A.  Hats off to you!

Comment: All of these are correct except 29A. :)

Answer (score 3):

### Partial answer

21. Destroy with blend of root and condensed performance-enhancing drugs (7)

> TORPEDO ("condensed performance-enhancing drugs" gives PED; torpedo is an anagram of "root ped" and things can be destroyed with it)

Comment: "Torpedo" has a verb form that actually means "destroy". :)

Answer (score 3):

10A. Measure boundless squats/tumbles at open-source hub (5)

> QUOTA: boundless squats = QUAT, open-source = O, O is the hub, so QUOAT, tumbles at the hub QUOTA

4D. At center, all eyes on friend flipping a fish (7)

> TILAPIA: All eyes on friend = I + PAL + I, At center = A + IPALI + T, Flipping = TILAPIA